# how can i get the number of items in implode?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a variable of ingredient name and ingredient value

I wanted to know if they have equal number of items. I used implode.

for ex.`ingredient_name['chicken'^'meat'^'water'] = 3` .

```
     $ingredient_name =implode("^",$_POST["mytext"]);
     $ingredient_value = implode("^", $_POST["mytext2"]);
```

Comment: Did you try with `count();`? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: are $_POST["mytext"] and $_POST["mytext2"] arrays ? If so just do a count($_POST["mytext"])

Comment: you can use sizeof($ingredient_name); and
sizeof($ingredient_value);

Comment: Please read basic documentation . 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: i already tried that sizeof and count on ingredient_name and value 
but it gave me an output of 1,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`implode` takes array as a parameter so your code should work fine with

implode("^",$_POST["mytext"]);
implode("^",$_POST["mytext2"]);

so

```
if(count($_POST["mytext"])===($_POST["mytext2"])) echo "equal";
```

should do the job

Comment: nice good! quick answer i tried to count the $ingredient_name but they gave me 1,1

Comment: They will always give you one, because implode join them, explode returns an array based on the value given and splitting char sequence